# Service worker not caching https responses

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a service worker for a vue pwa. Its able to cache assets but I cant figure out how to cache http responses. According to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6H1wftPS0oo) I am supposed to see `api-cache` in Cache Storage list

**vue.config.vue**

```
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    workboxPluginMode: "InjectManifest",
    workboxOptions: {
      swSrc: "./src/sw.js",
      swDest: "service-worker.js",
      navigateFallback: "/index.html",
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: new RegExp(
            "^https://<api>.<domain>.co.za/"
          ),
          handler: "networkFirst",
          options: {
            networkTimeoutSeconds: 2000,
            cacheName: "api-cache",
            cacheableResponse: {
              statuses: [0, 200]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

**registerServiceWorker.js**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready () {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.'
      )
    },
    registered (registration) {
      setInterval(() => {
        registration.update();
      }, 1000 * 60 * 60);

      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached () {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound () {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated (registration) {
      document.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('swUpdated', { detail: registration })
      );
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you click on the single cache items within `cache storage`, do you see your API Url in any of them?

Comment: @Francesco no it is not on the list of urls

Comment: Have you tried to use a static URL in the "urlPattern" field instead of a RegEx? There can be maybe a typo or a wrong value sent on runtime and the regex does not match with the API URL. If you do not see it in the cache storage, it means exactly that (no URL match).

Comment: @Francesco static url does not make a difference.

Comment: the service worker module seems to be correctly imported and the SW is registered on the client, therefore all seems fine until there. If even by using a "hardcoded" URL it still does not cache the API Response, then the issue seems definitively related to the caching setup, that is not just a typo. Unfortunately I do not have experience with Vue, but I wrote an article to cache APIs with Angular: https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular (just in case you might find some possible hints on what is missing on your side)

Comment: @Francesco thanks. This is the tutorial repo forked (it works on the video tutorial) https://github.com/dlodeprojuicer/zip when it still does not work even if I deploy as is.

Comment: Ionic vue is still in beta `"@ionic/vue": "0.0.4"` I suspect this might have something to do with it

Answer (score 0):

It might well be that the package `@ionic/vue` is the reason.

If you can, I would suggest to try to implement your PWA with workbox. It is a set of node libraries, therefore you can embed in your Vue app.

In the same article suggested in the comments, I give also an [Overview about Workbox](https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#wbox).

Some articles related to using Workbox with Vue PWA:

- https://www.blog.plint-sites.nl/adding-workbox-to-a-vue-cli-pwa/
- https://www.telerik.com/blogs/offline-first-vue-apps-with-hoodie-workbox